# Line chart of values at irregular intervals over time, data from mysql

Tags: php, chart.js

I'm working on creating a website where users will be able to keep a log of their skills progression on various tasks over time (using a generic 0 to 100 ranking). As part of this, I want users to be able to display a historic line chart displaying values they've logged and the date/time they logged them.

Below is an image from a website that I frequent (GPLRank) that uses a similar concept where it displays a time handicap as tracked over time, where the x-axis is time and the y-axis is a handicap in seconds (compared to a benchmark). For my purposes, I would want the x-axis to stay as time, but I would have the y-axis be a value from 0 to 100.

[image: GPLRank handicap history]

I've found plenty of examples online using things like chart.js, but nothing that quite fits what I'm looking for where the values are recorded at irregular intervals. For instance, users of my site might log ten values today, but then might not log any again for several days or weeks.

My site is largely based in PHP and I know very little javascript. However, I'm open to the idea of using some scripting to make this happen.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of using time on x axis. Don't forget the luxon, chartjs-adapter-luxon libraries, order is important.

```js
// '+new Date('2022-01')' return time in milliseconds 1640995200000
const exampleData = [{
    "x": +new Date('2022-01'),
    "y": 1000
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-02'),
    "y": 11000
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-05'),
    "y": 5000
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-06'),
    "y": 5500
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-07'),
    "y": 7000
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-08'),
    "y": 7000
  },
  {
    "x": +new Date('2022-09'),
    "y": 7000
  },
]


const chartCfg = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      borderColor: 'green',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointStyle: 'cross',
      data: exampleData,
      label: 'example',
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
             month: 'yyyy-MM',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const chartCtx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(chartCtx, chartCfg);
chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '400px';
chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '300px';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.4.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-adapter-luxon/1.1.0/chartjs-adapter-luxon.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="chart""></canvas>
```