# chart.js (3.8.0) line chart not showing

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I'm trying to add a chart to my website to show the prices of cryptocurrencies, which the user selects, by taking them from an endpoint on my website. After taking the data from the endpoint I add it to the array with the graph data via a push and then I update the graph with the update function, all performed within a setInterval every 5 seconds. Even if inside the arrays I find both the data and the labels that I insert, the graph is not shown.
The part of the code shown is inside a PHP file.
Where am I doing wrong?

```
            <div>
                <canvas class="realTimeGraph" id="realTimeGraph"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var ctx = document.getElementById("realTimeGraph").getContext('2d');
                const BaseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/CryptoSite/php/dbEndpoint.php?crypto="
                let chartCryptoData = [];
                let data = {
                    labels: [],
                    dataset: [{
                        label: "Crypto price",
                        data: [],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    }]
                };
                const config = {
                    type: 'line',
                    data : data,
                    options : {}
                };

                function getPriceData__(url, callback) 
                {
                    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                    xhttp.responseType = 'json';
                    xhttp.send();

                    xhttp.onload = () => {
                        var status = xhttp.status;
                        if (status === 200) {
                            callback(null, xhttp.response);
                        } else {
                            callback(status, xhttp.response);
                        }
                    };
                }

                async function getPriceData() {
                    let cryptoForGraph = "<?php echo $_SESSION['cryptoForGraph']?>";
                    let url = BaseUrl + cryptoForGraph

                    await getPriceData__(url,
                        function (err, data) {
                            if (err !== null) {
                                console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
                            }
                            chartCryptoData.push({
                                x: data['timestamp'],
                                y: data['price']
                            });
                    });
                }

                function setLabels(labels, timestamp) {
                    labels.push(timestamp);
                    labels.shift();
                }

                function setData(data, price) {
                    data.push(price);
                    data.shift();
                }

                document.getElementById("showCryptoGraph").onclick = () => {
                    console.log("button press");

                    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

                    setInterval( () => {
                        getPriceData();
                        let currentData = chartCryptoData.pop();
                        if(currentData !== undefined)
                        {
                            setData(config.dataset[0].data, currentData.y);
                            setLabels(config.labels, currentData.x);

                            myLineChart.update();
                            console.log("end intervall");
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                };
            </script>
```

Comment: x axis is time? Do you import time and adapter library? One of my examples [x axis time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72890806/line-chart-of-values-at-irregular-intervals-over-time-data-from-mysql/72894415#72894415)

Comment: the x-axis is the time of the price, but I take it from the endpoint, as u can see from the code, and it is a string so I don't think I need a time adapter. The issue I run into it is that even if the chart has the data in the "data" and "labels" array it didn't show it. The price too is a string and i tried to cast it as a float, but the issue persist.

Comment: maybe it will tell you something, I do it like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aaqup/7fac2Lms/106/)